# Adjust Manipulator/Gizmo Hotspot Blender 2.8

Tags: animation, 3d-manipulator, gizmo

I was wondering if there was a way to adjust the Gizmo hot spots for the axis representers like in Blender 2.79?

This is the old setting:
[image]

This is the new setting:

[image]

Right now it seems like it only activates the axis when i'm directly on it.

Does anyone know how to edit this?